# Сортировка внутри SQL запроса

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть нечто подобное:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN
(13849,74209,13828,14093,14114,52536,12758,12759,12769,13809,13810,74209)
```

Нужно что в выборке элементы были отсортированы в соответствии с их положением в списке.  Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это делается с помощью функции [FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function%5Ffield):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (13849,74209,13828,14093,14114,52536,12758,12759,12769,13809,13810,74209)
ORDER BY FIELD(id,13849,74209,13828,14093,14114,52536,12758,12759,12769,13809,13810,74209)
```